# @font-face and -ms-filter cutting off letters in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

In a recent project I picked up from a colleague, we had an issue where the top part of a @font-face was being cut off in IE8:

[image: Screenshot of font issue.]

The font in question appears to be taller than the browser expects, and it's this part that gets chopped off.

[image: Screenshot of font issue.]

The blue highlight is IE8's console highlighting the h1 element.

I was just going to put this down to a quirk of IE8 until I realised that the h1 tag was sat on an element with a scaling background, which uses an ms-filter:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/nav/intro-3.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
```

If I remove this, the font displays correctly.

My question is, what causes this odd behaviour? Is there a workaround?

As mentioned in the comment below, since a Fiddle could be useful:

http://jsfiddle.net/pV2TP/

You'll need to view it embedded for Fiddle to work in IE8:

http://jsfiddle.net/pV2TP/embedded/result/

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Mooseman Good shout - I've thrown one together and added it to the original post. It replicates the issue when viewed in IE8.